# Django-React integration Django port does not actualize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, port

I made changes to the src/app.js when I use npm start inside the react_app, in port 3000 changes and gets rendered but when I do that using python manage.py runserver I only see the default react-app welcome how can I fix that?

views

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Heres is my react_app inside my django project here is the app.js

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Calendar App</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

using python manage.py runserver:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h93R2.png)

using npm run inside react app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbprE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any change you make to the project you initialized with `create-react-app`, running `npm start` to start your project [will handle `hot-reloading` for you.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#npm-start-or-yarn-start)
This is no longer so when you run your code using Django. Django will serve the site as is so any changes you make after will **not be automatically reloaded**.
Running with Django will then look like this:

- Make changes to your code
- Recompile your code (you can do so with `npm run build`)
- Restart your Django server (you can do so with `python manage.py runserver`)

The assumption is that you have successfully integrated your static files (written with ReactJS) into Django.

Comment: Thanks, bro is there any way to run production better how do you personally do this?do you do this every time you make changes?

Comment: That is exactly how I run it. I communicate with the backend using rest API’s and websockets (using Django channels of course). After I am done with my app, I build and host using Django.

Comment: Vite or websockets

Comment: No you misunderstood me. I expose my Django views via rest APIs